PrimeNG TreeSelect: Programmatic selection does not propagate
When selecting nodes in a checkbox-based treselect using mouse clicks, the default behavior is to propagate selection up the tree so that ancestors will be either selected or partially selected, as required.
When setting the selection for a tree programmatically the expected behavior is that this propagation would also take place, but it currently does not.
This bug is pretty onerous to work around. Correctly propagating this state manually requires a considerable amount of code, especially if you want to handle all the possible cases, like choosing non-leaf nodes, propagating both up and down, and distinguishing partial- and full-selection (since one is managed by modifying the contents of the node tree itself, and the other is managed by manipulating the actual selection value). The existing implementation of propagation does not seem to be packaged in a way that allows users of the library to easily trigger the existing logic directly, so a manual workaround produces significant code duplication.
Does anyone know how we can resolve the issue?
Steps to reproduce the behavior
See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselect-demo-rddvht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json
Expected behavior
Whenver a tree, treeselect, or other related component has its selection modified, even it is being modified programmatically, the configured propagation behavior should be allowed to take place.

Well, i had a similar problem with p-treetable and I ended up to add a new property in the data structure, isSelected and manage manually the state of all the checkboxes.. :( And even with the manual state set it was still buggy

Coming back with a 'workaround' ish, after a bit of searching i came up with this combination, instead of using p-dropdown a p-tree with p-overlayPanel  might do the same thing  PrimeNG TreeSelectHardcodedOptions Maybe something from here will be helpful for what you have :)

I faced the same problem yesterday. Programmatically assignment to the [(selection)] field of p-tree did not propagate to selection. it seems as it is related a unsolved bug in primeng: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12714
Here is my p-tree concept, it is single selection mode(not checkbox or etc):
<p-tree [value]="treeData" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode" (onNodeSelect)="selectNode($event)">

I wrote a workaround for programmatically selection, which method manually expands the tree to the specific node:
private selectAndExpandParent(selectedNode: TreeNode) {
    selectedNode.expanded = true;
    selectedNode.partialSelected = true; //this is necessary(for primeng) for programmatically selection.
    if (selectedNode.parent) {
        this.selectAndExpandParent(selectedNode.parent);
    }
}

I did not know inner implementation of primeng, but only assigning expanded = true does not enough for propogation, partial selected should also be true in the tree-path to selected node.
